# how to simulate user's touch on IOS using pythonista

Tags: python, ios, pythonista

I would like to use the IOS app Pythonista to simulate a touch every 5 seconds somewhere specific on the screen. Similar to what one could do with PyautoGUI on a computer

I would like to use my own phone and not a virtual phone on my computer
is there any way i can do that ?